# pubsubhubbub link with Project Rome

Tags: java, rss, websub

I want to use [Project Rome](https://rome.dev.java.net/) to create an RSS feed, using the [code from the tutorial](http://wiki.java.net/bin/view/Javawsxml/Rome05TutorialFeedWriter) as base. I would like to add a pubsubhubbub discovery link, but there doesn't seem to be a general way to do so.

I can use a `Link` object if I create an atom feed (which I don't want to limit myself to), or I can just add foreign markup, like this:

```
// import org.jdom.Element

Element element = new Element("link");
element.setAttribute("rel", "hub");
element.setAttribute("href", "https://myhub.example.com/endpoint");

feed.setForeignMarkup(Arrays.asList(element));
```

But it feels ugly.

Is this really the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Project rome has moved to http://rometools.org.
It has a incubator project [certiorem](https://rometools.jira.com/wiki/display/INCUBATOR/Certiorem+Tutorial) for pubsubhubbub that looks promising as it is already mavenized:

Comment: Since adding above answer I have joined Rome Certiorem project (implementing pubsubhubbub) as a committer and we have done a release of the project. I have been using this project in a production project with good success.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very familiar with Rome, but I guess it works. If you indeed your RSS (and not ATOM), make sure you:

- Dont forget to add the Atom namespace to this `<link>` item (which isn't part of the RSS2.0 spec
- Add another link (Atom too) with `rel = "self"` which points to the corresponding url.

Finally, you may want to edit your title by adding "hubbub" to "pubsub", since PubSub is more general and is more often used in the context of XMPP XEP 060.